# Import with @ in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to adapt a Next.js template to start a new project. However, this type of import which I have seen in previous projects.

```
import config from "@config/config.json";
import theme from "@config/theme.json";
```

I would like to know how to do this type of import with @. What term should I search the documentation with to achieve this?

I would appreciate any explanation.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases

Answer (score 2):

create a jsconfig.json at root of your directory and

```json
 {
 "compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": ".",
   "paths": {
     "@ClientApp/*": ["./ClientApp/*"]
   }
 }
}
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

if you use React Typescript, to create shortcut/alias first you need to add a file at root folder called `tsconfig.base.json` if doesn't exist there, then, add your shortcuts as the example given below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",   
  "paths": {
      "@myproject/my-api": ["libs/my-api/src/index.ts"],
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These imports are used by scoped npm packages.

To make use of an import like these, there should be an npm package with the scope/name that you are using.

You can have locally something like this:

```js
import foo from './@config/config.json';
```

Then you should create a directory with name "@config".

Comment: Yes, but I was talking about the path beautifier with @. The dev must to do the setup jsconfig.json or tsconfig. Thanks for comment.